# Pasting and writing data onto existing Excel file using R

Tags: r, excel, extract, export-to-excel

Let's say I already have an existing Excel workbook where the cells are formatted aesthetically. How do I paste the data in a specific column into the Excel workbook that may have merged cells?

Using iris as an example, if I want to paste the first 10 data of the Species column onto cells AG18 to AG27 of the existing Excel workbook, but the cell column AG is merged up to cell column AJ (meaning that AG18 AH18 AI18 AJ18 are merged into one cell), how do I go about doing this? The following code gave me a corrupted Excel file when executing it:

```
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx)

# Extract the data from iris
data <- iris$Species[1:10]

# Load the target workbook
target_wb <- loadWorkbook("existingExcel.xlsx")

# Select the sheet and range to paste the data to
target_sheet <- "existingSheet"
target_range <- "AG18:AG27"

# Write the data to the target workbook
writeData(target_wb, sheet = target_sheet, x = data, startCol = 33, startRow = 18)


# Save the target workbook
saveWorkbook(target_wb, "target_file.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: The issue is that you have `x = df` instead of `x = data` in your writeData(.... line!

Comment: You may want merged cells for a formatted report, but they should be avoided anywhere you are managing or calculating on data. See this useful paper for advice on data management in spreadsheets: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00031305.2017.1375989

Comment: @TarJae Ah, yes, thank you for pointing that out. However, even with ```x = data```, it still outputs a corrupt Excel file that cannot be saved.

Comment: @JonSpring The target workbook is in fact a formatted report in Excel, though I'm trying to see if it's really possible to paste iris$Species data into specified merged cells in Excel so that we don't have to reformat the target workbook.

Comment: This sounds tricky and brittle. Perhaps it might work better if you specify to openxlsx to merge the cells it outputs to match the destination? https://rdrr.io/cran/openxlsx/man/mergeCells.html

Answer (score 1):

Probably the corruption is simply caused by some minor `openxlsx` bug. If you want to give `openxlsx2` a try, the following should do what you want. The code is similar to `openxlsx`, but in `openxlsx2` we have added a few more fail-saves to prevent worksheet corruption.

```r
library(openxlsx2)

### example file
setwd(tempdir())

# create worksheet
wb <- wb_workbook() %>% 
  wb_add_worksheet("existingSheet")

# create merged rows AG1:AJ1; AG2:AJ2; ...
for (row in 1:100) {
  wb <- wb_merge_cells(
    wb = wb,
    cols = col2int("AG"):col2int("AJ"),
    rows = row
  )
}

wb %>% 
  wb_add_cell_style(dims = "AG1:AG100", horizontal = "center") %>% 
  wb_save("existingExcel.xlsx")

rm(wb)
### end create worksheet

# Extract the data from iris
data <- iris$Species[1:10]

# Load the target workbook
target_wb <- wb_load("existingExcel.xlsx")

# Select the sheet and range to paste the data to
target_sheet <- "existingSheet"
target_range <- "AG18:AG27"

# Write the data to the target workbook
wb_add_data(
  wb = target_wb,
  sheet = target_sheet,
  dims = target_range,
  x = data
) %>% wb_save(
  "updatedExcel.xlsx"
)

# xl_open("updatedExcel.xlsx")
```